# How to get the path and set into the variable

Tags: batch-file

Basically i'm using an installer to form an exe file i.e retry.exe . This retry.exe file consists of a  folder named **demo** which consists of some files. During installation or double clicking to i.e retry.exe to a machine i have an option to browse the folder in any of my desirable location i.e i can browse to **C folder**  or **D folder** of windows 7 O.S system and install my **demo** folder. So how can i get the path of **demo** folder and set into a variable using a batch file script ?
After googling ,i came to know that **pushd %~dp0** may work but dont have much idea of it though i'm very new to batch file scripting. Any answers will be highly appriciated.

Comment: The question is very unclear. Try to attach a code of your batch with comment in place in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the batch file is running from the `demo` folder then `%cd%` will return the full path of the folder it is in.

With your added info, this should work but can take a long time though.  This searches drive C: and if the folder is not found it searches drive D:

```
@echo off
set "folder="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "c:\demo22112" /b /s /ad ') do if /i "%%~nxa"=="demo22112" set "folder=%%a"
if not defined folder for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "d:\demo22112" /b /s /ad ') do if /i "%%~nxa"=="demo22112" set "folder=%%a"
echo "%folder%"
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm sorry , i think my question is not clear. I have separate batch file through which i need to get the location of the folder demo . I Just know that demo folder is at any location in the system. Is my question is still unclear ?
Just search the location or path and set into the variable

Comment: A batch file can search for a folder named `demo` but if it has to search every drive then it could take a long time - and it may find other folders that are also named `demo`

Comment: Ohk but that will do . I will give my folder name as demo22112 . So now how can i get the path of this folder ?

Comment: Thank u so much. 2 thing more :- 1:- If i need to search both the directory i.e C drive and D drive then do i have to use another for loop?......
2:- IF the folder demo22112 consists of many files then can i search 1 specific file i.e demoee.txt using this?

Comment: I added a second loop which will run if the folder is not found on c: and if you want to change the question to include files then open a new question.

Comment: thanx again @foxidrive . Will surely open a new question if i couldn't get answer.Let me try it by myself first :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask user for a folder. There is no standard way of doing such with batch.

Some options:

1) Ask user to type directory and check it:

```
SET /P "Directory=Enter desired directory: "
IF NOT EXIST "%Directory%\" GOTO Not_Directory_Error
```

2) Use [vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript) to browse for a directory and returning it to batch.